# Html5 Chunk Upload not working in Chrome 25?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I have the following code to upload an image in chunk using Html5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form>
<div class="example">
    #bytes/chunk:
    <input id="numChunks" value="1048576" />
    <input id="files" class="button" type="file" />
    <div id="bars">
        <span id="numofchunks">Num of chunks: </span>
        <br />
        <span id="message"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
            var blob = this.files[0];

            var BYTES_PER_CHUNK = (1024 * 1024) / 2; // 1MB chunk sizes.
            var SIZE = blob.size;
            $('#numofchunks').text($('#numofchunks').text() + SIZE / BYTES_PER_CHUNK);
            var start = 10;
            var end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
            var counter = 1;
            while (start < SIZE) {
                upload(blob.slice(start, end), counter);

                start = end;
                end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }, false);

    });

        function upload(blobOrFile, counter) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/basic/html5', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
            //            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", blobOrFile.fileName);
            xhr.onload = function () { $('#message').text($('#message').text() + counter + "  ") };

            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("fileToUpload", blobOrFile);
            xhr.send(fd);
        };


</script>
```

This is working in all the browsers but its not working in my Chrome. In Chrome I don't receive the request on Server. In the chrome network tracking it always show the request as Pending.

**UPDATE**: I am not able to upload a big file (more than 1mb). It does not matter I chunk it or not or the size of the chunk. If the image size is more than 1mb it does not upload.

Please see the attached screenshot of the error
[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that `this.files[0]` will not work in versions of IE lower than 10.

Comment: What happens if you pass the whole file?

Comment: @James: Thanks, You are correct for IE. But we are trying to solve Chrome issue.

Comment: @Jack: It does not upload if file size is more than 1mb. Please see my update

Comment: I am able to pass whole file (up to 500mb )by adding these changes to web.config: <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="524288000" executionTimeout="120000" />
</system.web>
 
 
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>

Comment: But I want to chunk the file not send it whole togother

Comment: Have you tried `.webkitSlice()` instead of `.slice()`? Certain browsers have prefixed their slice methods.

Comment: @Jack: Thax a lot, but 'webkitSlice()' is not supported now, so chrome supports 'slice()' method only

Comment: One more thing you could try; remove the `xhr.setRequestHeader()` statement.

Comment: @Jack: not working :( , thx

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem, but why are you using `querySelector` when you have jQuery?

Comment: It works in Chrome 26.0.1410.64. Are you sure that not a single chunk request is sent by Chrome to the server?

Comment: @MårtenWikström: I have chrome 26.0.1410.64 but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function(){
            var blobs = [];

/*
 * function that uploads a fragment of the file
 */
        function uploadChunk(blob, fileName, fileType){

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open('POST', 'upload_chunks.cfm', false);

            xhr.onload = function(e){
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += "Chunk of size " + blob.size + " uploaded successfully.<br/>";
            }

            xhr.setRequestHeader('X_FILE_NAME', fileName);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', fileType)
            document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += "Uploading chunk of size " + blob.size + ".<br/>";
            xhr.send(blob);
        }

/*
 * Invoke this function when the file is selected.
 */
        document.querySelector('#userfile').addEventListener('change', function(){
            var file = this.files[0];
            var bytes_per_chunk = 1024 * 1024;
            var start = 0;
            var end = bytes_per_chunk;
            var size = file.size;

            while (start < size) {
    //push the fragments to an array
                blobs.push(file.slice(start, end));
                start = end;
                end = start + bytes_per_chunk;
            }

    //upload the fragment to the server
            while (blob = blobs.shift()) {
    uploadChunk(blob, file.name, file.type);
            }
        })
    })();
```

From http://www.sagarganatra.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried your code and it is giving this error: Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 Html5:71
uploadChunk Html5:71
(anonymous function) , from the first chunk

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution

https://github.com/tbela99/uploadManager/tree/master/Source

Credit goes to Thierry Bela